# @line/bot-sdk in azure not working

Tags: node.js, azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service, package.json

I create a web application in Azure.

And deploy from a repository in bitbucket.

but azure always give me this error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@line/bot-sdk'
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "linebot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@line/bot-sdk": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "*@line/bot-sdk*" has not been installed properly. First, please make sure the `package.josn` is located in root folder of the Repository.

[image]

Once you push your code to bitbucket, **Kudu** will sync the repository to `/site/wwwroot` on Azure App Service and run `npm install --production` here by executing the deployment script.

```
:: 3. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)
```

Finally, you may want to check dependencies whether or not they have been installed via **App Service Editor** (`https://[YouAppName].scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`).

[image]

Comment: I type `ls node_modules` in azure console window, I cannot find "@line" folder inside. But it is really exist in BitBucker repo.